# Как в Drawer (боковое меню) разместить над statusBar?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Подскажите пожалуйста, как Drawer (боковое меню) разместить над statusBar? На фото образец стороннего приложения того, что я хочу получить. За основу взял стандартный проект android -studio. (File - new - выбрал проект с дравером)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так ты хотя бы покажи его реализацию, может ты либу какую использовал. Информации не достаточно

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: Ничего не использовал, создал новый проект и пытаюсь там drawer настроить. android:fitsSystemWindows="true" не помогает

Comment: @ivansoft нужно добавить fitsystem windows true и при этом еще в стилях там где главная тема прописать <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true< как то так вроде

Answer (score 0):

Согласно руководству Material Design, Navigation drawer [должен занимать всю высоту экрана, но находится за status bar](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы посмотреть как это реализовано (компоновка layout'ов, представлений и их атрибутов) и затем реализовать у себя — достаточно создать новый проект и выбрать начальный шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]